# Can I set stage names in spark ML Pipelines?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline

I'm starting to create more complex ML pipelines and using the same type of pipeline stage multiple times.  Is there a way to set the name of stages so that someone else can easily interrogate the pipeline that is saved and find out what is going on? e.g.

```
vecAssembler1 = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["P1", "P2"], outputCol="features1")
vecAssembler2 = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["P3", "P4"], outputCol="features2")
lr_1 = LogisticRegression(labelCol = "L1")
lr_2 = LogisticRegression(labelCol = "L2")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler1, vecAssembler2, lr_1, lr_2])
print pipeline.stages
```

this will return something like this:

```
[VectorAssembler_4205a9d090177e9c54ba, VectorAssembler_42b8aa29277b380a8513, LogisticRegression_42d78f81ae072747f88d, LogisticRegression_4d4dae2729edc37dc1f3]
```

but what I would like is to do something like:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler1, vecAssembler2, lr_1, lr_2], names=["VectorAssembler for predicting L1","VectorAssembler for predicting L1","LogisticRegression for L1","LogisticRegression for L2")
```

so that a saved pipeline model can be loaded by a third party and they will get nice descriptions:

```
print pipeline.stages
# [VectorAssembler for predicting L1,VectorAssembler for predicting L2,LogisticRegression for L1,LogisticRegression for L2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [_resetUid](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a8a3e9b7cf7b9346c43cfbbf7b26fd2fd28dd521/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py#L488) method to rename each transformer/estimator:

```
vecAssembler1 = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["P1", "P2"], outputCol="features1")
vecAssembler1._resetUid("VectorAssembler for predicting L1")
```

By default it uses java's UID random generator.

Comment: Now that I'm using this - it works on the pipeline I create, but not when saved and loaded. I guess when loaded again new instances of all the stages are created and the default it uses java's UID random generator is used again.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What spark version do you use? Try to check spark-2.3: [seems like this commit added support](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/35db3b9fe38dadfb8afb0b0857c09f83196398be#diff-e2d0fc095c5af03879cee6f83f000030R210)

Comment: Great. No I'm using 2.2 at the moment. Looking forward to 2.3 but waiting for the org to catch up! Thanks

Comment: Hi @prudenko, I am facing the same issue. Uids are changing while loading the saved model. I am using pyspark 2.4.4. Will you please give some example of how we can persist these uids while saving so that we get them as it is after loading the pipelineModel